# Separate header for static home page and posts page

Tags: customization, headers

My custom headers are located in the folder `/parts/header/` and header selection is controlled using theme panel, so I tried write like this in my `header.php` but came out blank header in static front page, please advice.

```
if (is_front_page() ) {
   get_header( '/parts/header/header-style-11.php' );

} else {
  /*
   * loads the header template set in Theme Panel -> Header area
   * the template files are located in ../parts/header
   */
   td_api_header_style::_helper_show_header();

   do_action('td_wp_booster_after_header'); //used by unique articles
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify a path in `get_header()`, but rather a name. So for example:

```
get_header( 'home' );
```

This will load `header-home.php` from the main theme directory.

Comment: In my case header.php is in main directory and **header-style-11.php** is located in **main-directory/parts/header/**, that is the header I am trying to call. I can try placing in same directory.

Comment: Move them into the main theme directory with `style.css` and give them meaningful names